# Why Cross Validated is not in the list of possible migrations?

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

There is a lot of data mining and machine learning questions without a specific code info which best fit to be in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But Cross Validated is not in the list of migration sites of SO. Why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sites are only listed in the target list if they are in the top 5 of *actual* migrations, determined by number of migrations and the success rate.

Cross Validated is not in that top 5; in the past 90 days only 39 posts have been migrated (with 5% rejections). Compare this to the current #1 migration target, DBA.SE, with 309 migrations.

When you come across a post that is *off-topic* for Stack Overflow *and* is high-quality, you can flag it for moderator attention (choose 'other'), and explain that the post should be migrated to CR.

Just because it is interesting: Cross Validated migrated 216 questions *in the other direction*; it is the second most active source of migrated posts, after Programmers and way ahead of #3 (Super User with 55 migrations). Apparently CR is getting many more off-topic questions than Stack Overflow is getting CR questions!

Comment: I think the policy is bogus!

Comment: @SAM: why do you feel that policy is bogus? Why should CR be listed when it makes up but a small portion of migrations? We have objective metrics here to use, why ignore those?

Comment: Maybe CR and a lot of Q&A sites on SE have a small portion of migration and sum of them is noticeable! Many people does not know about other sites of SE.

Comment: @SAM: You can easily teach people with a simple comment. And no, the sum of the smaller site migrations is not noticeable, really.

Comment: @SAM: You can always flag a post, choose 'other', and explain to the moderator you want the post migrated.

Comment: Well, I will do that. But it is not clean ;)

Comment: CV has a lot more migrations than SharePoint for the last 90 days, just by the way (even though there are possibly better candidates). I would suggest removing SharePoint from the list, but I'm not sure what to replace it with, and it doesn't really affect me enough.

Comment: The *non-beta* sites in the migration stats for the past 90 days account for 269 migrations, *in total*. DBA still beats that all on its own. The top 5 saw 784 migrated posts coming their way in total. I excluded beta sites as they are never eligible for inclusion in the migration target list.