# Migration to Portugese site not offered / no close reason not English language

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration, english

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157415/como-pasar-a-prolog-puro-peano) <s>would need migration to pt.stackoverflow. The options for migration currently offer only English sites</s>

.. is in another language. There is no specific close reason for it.

Suggestion 1: add pt.stackoverflow to the options offered for migration/

Suggestion 2: add close reason "other language than English"

Comment: That looks more like Spanish than Portuguese to me.

Comment: Perfect point ...

Comment: _Suggestion 2: add close reason "other language than English"_ - you are aware that there is a free-form text field under "off-topic->other", right? There's no need to add a fixed close reason for a very rare case like this.

Comment: @l4mpi: Right, but just look how it was closed: Confusing for the beginner - with a lengthy and inadequate sentence.

Comment: @false One could actually argue that "unclear" makes sense here, as it links to the "how to ask" page, which a custom reason would not do. That's pretty much the best resource we can give in this case - however I assume it will go utterly unnoticed, as you have to be [insert favourite expletives here] to post a non-english question here. Some user also left a comment stating that posts should be in english. If the OP is still confused, then there's no helping them anyways.

Comment: The five sites listed for migration are the top five  of successful migrations (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251787/why-cross-validated-is-not-in-the-list-of-possible-migrations). *"Unclear what you're asking"* is already sufficient for *"...because it isn't in English"*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290281/multilingual-support-for-stackoverflow http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/3204551

Answer (score 22):

The number of questions asked in *all* foreign languages is tiny, probably a single-digit number per day or fewer. It's not worth it to clutter the close dialog with options to migrate to the existing foreign language sites just for the very small number of questions that we might migrate.

In addition to that, the vast majority of us are incabable of judging the quality of questions written in foreign languages, so we shouldn't be migrating them even if we could. Just flag or vote to close them as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: The current behavior, while consistent with SE policies, appears very hostile to neophytes.

Comment: @false Closing a question isn't an act of hostility.

Comment: It is not the closing as such, rather the overly bureaucratic answer that can only be understood by SE insiders.

Comment: @false If I go to a site and I only see posts and documentation in Chinese, I'm not going to start posting in English and expect a response in English. I don't see what's hard to understand about this policy. It's not specific to SE.

Comment: Your very reasoning only seems to fade by the number of languages you actively speak.

Comment: @false I don't know what that means.

Comment: Think it means "If you go to a site and see posts in Chinese, and one post is in English, but you _speak_ English, you should also be allowed to post in English". Can't see what it else it could mean, however confusing that explanation is

Comment: @Clive: No. It means: If the text accompanied with closing an inappropriate question (as this one) is so complex that you need very elaborate reading skills and further some SE inside knowledge, the effect this has to an outsider is very appalling. Even more so if the outsider has (probably) a poor command of English. A simple-to-understand, polite answer would help a lot.

Comment: @false: From the "Unclear what you're asking" close message: _"As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."_ Yea, that's Harvard-grade English there. If one can't understand a message like that, I wonder what that person's doing on a English Q/A site

Comment: Sorry you've lost me, which text do you think is _so complex that you need very elaborate reading skills and further some SE inside knowledge_? Maybe you can edit that into your question so we know what you're specifically referring to?

Comment: @false I agree that the person who posted that question is very unlikely to understand the close message. I'm not sure what we can do about it, though, short of a custom close message in every language. If they understood English at all, they wouldn't have posted a question to SO in Spanish.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: "Please use English. Ask your question again." Something along this might be more helpful. No deep justification - it will not be understood anyway - simply because the situation is too surprising and in such situations reading skill drops by quite a few grades.

Comment: @false: And how would you suggest SO recognizes when the question is in a language other than English? A new close vote reason?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, that is Suggestion 2. It is necessary to ensure that the response is simple and nice enough.

Comment: @false Somebody did post "Please, Questions and Answers should be in English" as a comment.

Comment: So far all you've said is that there's a problem with "the text". You haven't pointed out _what_ text you're talking about, nor what problem you have with it exactly. You also haven't provided an example of the "simple and nice enough" version that you would prefer to see. Is that information coming later?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Yes, but to an outsider, that is a tiny footnote after a very complex and incomprehensible text.

Comment: @false: If the OP doesn't speak English, what good would a English message asking them to post in English do?

Comment: @Cerbrus: There is a significant difference between a simple message and the current text.

Comment: Both messages are Greek to people that don't speak English.

Comment: @Cerbrus: With an increasing number of languages you actively use, you would soon realize that there are very different reading levels.

Comment: English is a secondary language to me. I'm pretty sure that both messages only require a basic understanding of the language to get the idea.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Dutch (I presume) and English are pretty close. The initial gap is  larger for romanic languages, and even larger for others.

Comment: @false: we cannot fix the confusing world of the internet for everyone. Posting on a site where *everything else* is in English means you need to take responsibility for your own comprehension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @false None of that really applies to the simple closure of a question. No one is being rude, calling names, harassing, or bullying anyone. (If they are, that's a separate issue that needs to be flagged for moderator attention.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Not if you take an outsider's viewpoint. Internally within SO/SE, all is fine.