# Add cross-(natural)language migration paths

Tags: feature-request, migration

Sometimes a question is asked in non-English, but still on the topic of programming ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58217580)). Such questions attract downvotes, which are most likely due to "can't read/understand" reason. In such a case I tried to simply vote for migration, but it appears that there are no migration paths to e.g. Ru.SO, Pt.SO etc..

Could these cross-language migration paths be added?

Comment: @gnat duping a FR to a FAQ...?

Comment: @AndrasDeak [answer in the duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/839601) seems to sufficiently cover and explain it

Comment: @gnat that doesn't seem to take into account foreign-language sister sites, does it? Presumably if the FR got implemented the FAQ could be edited.

Comment: we had discussion explicitly involving sister sites [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293950/839601) @AndrasDeak See also, [Closing feature requests as duplicates of general discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313903/839601)

Comment: @AndrasDeak "If the discussion provides a succinct reason for the rejection of the feature request (ideally, in the highest upvoted answer) then yes, it's absolutely ok to close..." (from discussion about such closings referred in my prior comment)

Answer (score 25):

I disagree for two reasons.

The first reason is that I wouldn't trust voters to be able to judge the language correctly. Bulgarian vs. Russian? Spanish vs. Portuguese? Heck, a lot of people can't even distinguish Chinese from Japanese.

The second reason is that the golden rule of migration is "don't migrate crap". If the voters can't read the question they won't be able to judge if the question is answerable at all. Migration could easily lead to a lot of noise on the target site.

Comment: It may even be *spam*, and not just crap.

Comment: But software could support it. [Google Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) tries to guess the language. Stack Exchange could benefit from a lot more automation.